# Tensorflow Module not found on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm using default version of Python(2.7) on Macbook Pro with High Sierra. I have installed default version of tensorflow, which is 1.9, with this command:

```
pip -V
>>>pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)

pip install tensorflow
pip list
```

`>>>tensorflow             1.9.0`

Then I fire up python:

```
python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Then I try to import tensorflow and get this error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
>>>
```

I have tried to follow the instructions multiple times with no success. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to run your code?  idle?, spyder? pycharm?  terminal? ...

Comment: I'm using mac terminal.

Comment: Did you use Anaconda to load a version of python?

Comment: Why use the ancient Python 2.7 that Apple ships when Python 3 has been out 10 years?

Comment: @jmh I have Anaconda on my machine and it works fine. I need non-anaconda environment for connectivity between Python and R.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, I have been using Python 3 for a while, but my requirements dictate that I use non-Anaconda Python 2.7 environment.

Comment: Well, that's an inconvenience but my answer below is still valid. Try using a virtual environment and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed tensorflow it might be associated with a different version of python. I suggest you run in virtual environments. Create a virtual environment and activate it. Then once its activated run `pip install tensorflow` and then try to run your code with your virtual environment still activated.

[This link](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) has a much better description of why you need virtual environments and how you install them.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It works, it turns out the problem was somewhere else.